# Angular : Does providedIn root solve all duplicate service problems?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a service marked as Injectable providedIn:root in a SharedModule

If the sharedModule is imported everywhere (in the AppModule, eager AND lazy loaded feature modules) will the providedIn:root prevent the service from being duplicated in the lazy loaded modules? (By duplicated, I mean another instance of the service as opposed to an application-wide singleton)

Comment: Take a look at this https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#providedIn. Additionally, you can also put some console logs in the constructor and inject your Injectable in places you want to test. If you see the console logs multiple times, there are multiple instances of your service. If you see just one, you have a singleton.

Comment: @user1861857, if you use provideIn:root, you needn't declare in providers in any module (just only import in the component.ts that you use it).

Answer (score 0):

Angular's docs have a very detailed explanation when it comes to resolution hierarchy: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#resolution-rules. Quote from the same page:

> If you have registered a provider for the same DI token at different levels, the first one Angular encounters is the one it uses to resolve the dependency. If, for example, a provider is registered locally in the component that needs a service, Angular doesn't look for another provider of the same service.

This means that every time you provide your service elsewhere (in a separate module or component), it will create a copy of it.